# ASP .NET Core - Deny access at the API level and allow at the method level based on the same JWT claim value

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to implement a solution for temporary access in ASP .NET Core 3.1. Temporary access is defined in a "temporary" claim that can have a value of true or false in the JWT token.
The problem comes down to two situations:

- if the claim is true, global access to the API should be denied except for some methods. [Authorize] should continue to function normally.
- if the claim is false, access to the entire API must be allowed according to the [Authorize] attribute.

At first I thought about using reflection, in the same way as [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] works, but Microsoft recommends using Policies and not implementing Attributes.

How would I solve this problem using Policies? Should I Use Policies?

Comment: `if the claim is false, access to the entire API must be allowed according to the [Authorize] attribute.`Not sure what is your scenario.If the claim is false,the api with authorize should not be accessed and return 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be accessed? Shouldn't the user be given temporary access with limited authorization in some situations? The [Authorize] attribute will validate the token and allow access. I want to add a claim validation logic on top of that. My main problem is that if I deny access to API (with an attribute) I can't allow it in a method.